# How should SharePoint Visual Studio projects that share each other's code be managed?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, projects-and-solutions, solution, wspbuilder

My SharePoint Visual Studio solution structure currently contains these projects:

- **Common:** contains extension methods, helpers, frequently used controls, etc.
- **Logging:** would normally be included in Common but contains calls to native methods so marked 'unsafe'
- **Site-specific project:** one for each distinct site, containing features, web parts, event receivers, etc. specific to that site
- **Console app:** console app projects as/if needed

I'm using WSPBuilder hence each project (apart from the console apps) has its own SharePoint WSP solution file.

Is this a good way to split up SharePoint code? What approaches do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems reasonable, though you might want to be careful about the deployment of the shared projects - The deployment script probably includes updating the common package, which isn't good for older site specific projects.

For most projects I prefer to have a single solution package with necessary shared libraries included - usually being installed to the GAC.

Comment: Good points here, though planning updates the the common package here should be SharePoint agnostic - the need to maintain backward compatibility is equally strong.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't doing this already, I would consider bundling your common code into one or more features and have the non-common code be in a feature with a feature dependency to the common code.  You may want to have the common code use a different WSP or the same WSP - not sure of all of the pros/cons of that.